Adding context to translations without using macros in Lingui
How can I turn this translation (that uses macros):
 i18n._(
          msg({
            context: "Validation",
            message: `${fieldLabel} should be before ${maxTime}.`,
          })
 ),

to something like this:
i18n._({
          id: "{fieldLabel} should be before {maxTime}.",
          message: "{fieldLabel} should be before {maxTime}.",
          values: {
            fieldLabel,
            maxTime,
          },
}),

I could find a way to include context without macros. My goals are:

Have a context
Have the message as its id
If no tranlsation is provided it should fall back to the message.

